# Entity Framework map one to many to one

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got into trouble in mapping tables with Entity Framework with the relationship is one to many to one.

To make it clear, here's the illustration of table classes

```
public class Human
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "must not be empty!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string HumanName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HumanFootwear> HumanFootwears { get; set; }
}
```

The Human footwear class (for grouping)

```
    public class HumanFootwear
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("HumanID"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual Human CHumans { get; set; }
        public long HumanID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FootwearID"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual Footwear Footwears { get; set; }
        public long FootwearID { get; set; }
    }
```

The footwear table class

```
public class Footwear
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "must not be empty!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying with the fluent API method, but I can't get make it to work

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
            .HasKey(key => key.ID)
            .HasMany(hm => hm.Footwear)
            .WithMany(wm => wm.Human)    
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.MapLeftKey("")
            });
```

I get a syntax error on "with many human",

> Cannot convert single `Human` class to `ICollection<Human>`

Am I doing it wrong? Should I map the human footwear instead?